# Tomcat catalina.out growing rapidly

Tags: java, tomcat

I see below messages in my catalina.out file. Every second I have over 50 of these statements getting printed, which is eating up all my disk space, and causing catalina to grow like crazy.

```
INFO  [Fri Feb 7 04:48:21 GMT 2014:] [http-bio-10080-exec-141] [] queueLog : Fri Feb 07 04:48:21 GMT 2014  TestReq:http://my-chattertest.com/stlp/RequestWeb--USER->demo
INFO  [Fri Feb 7 04:48:21 GMT 2014:] [http-bio-10080-exec-141] [] queueLog : Fri Feb 07 04:48:21 GMT 2014  TestReq:http://my-chattertest.com/stlp/RequestWeb--USER->demo
INFO  [Fri Feb 7 04:48:21 GMT 2014:] [http-bio-10080-exec-140] [] queueLog : Fri Feb 07 04:48:21 GMT 2014  TestReq:http://my-chattertest.com/stlp/RequestWeb--USER->demo
INFO  [Fri Feb 7 04:48:21 GMT 2014:] [http-bio-10080-exec-140] [] queueLog : Fri Feb 07 04:48:21 GMT 2014  TestReq:http://my-chattertest.com/stlp/RequestWeb--USER->demo
INFO  [Fri Feb 7 04:48:21 GMT 2014:] [http-bio-10080-exec-101] [] queueLog : Fri Feb 07 04:48:21 GMT 2014  TestReq:http://my-chattertest.com/stlp/RequestWeb--USER->demo
```

What could be causing this? I don't have any of the words in the log in my code. I have no clue where these statements are coming from. Please help me with your thoughts. If any of you have faced something similar to this? What could be causing it, and how do I prevent it?

Comment: If all else fails, run Tomcat in debug mode, put breakpoints in your logging API's logging methods and attach a debugger.

Comment: Is there an app running in that Tomcat instance that is being hit by a remote test system? What do the access logs say?